# DataGridView Checkbox Column Binding cannot able to edit in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, datagridview, wpf-controls

i am having table name as menu it contains (menuid, menuname, type, maker, checker). the maker and checker datatype is bit in database. the type it contains only E and R.

i am using visual studio 2012, LLBLgenPro, Moden UI

Now i am binding is Table data in datagridview my code is

```
 _dtsource = FormAccessPermissionsClass.MenuList().DefaultView;                
            Dgrid.ItemsSource = _dtsource;

            var MakerColumn = new FirstFloor.ModernUI.Windows.Controls.DataGridCheckBoxColumn();

            Binding bind = new Binding("Maker");
            bind.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;                
            MakerColumn.CellStyle = new Style(typeof(bool));
            MakerColumn.Binding = bind;
            MakerColumn.Header = "Maker";               

            Dgrid.Columns[3] = MakerColumn;
```

Now, my question is

```
 1. The checkbox are coming but i cannot able to edit (checked/unchecked) it.
 2. I want if type is E then checkbox is show otherwide hide it
```